# Mylyn's connector to Emacs org mode files?

Tags: github, org-mode, mylyn

Is there something like a mylyn connector to org mode files?

I'm a fan of both Mylyn and org mode, as some other people are. ([How do you organize your work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661204/how-do-you-organize-your-work)) Both of them are valuable task management tools: Mylyn on Eclipse and Org mode on Emacs. Org mode uses simple text files as task repository whereas Mylyn can be connected with a varieties of task repositories such as Git issue list, Jira (which I haven't used), etc. One feature I'd like to see from mylyn is that it should be also able to use org files as task repository.

Org files are favourable relative to most of the task repositories to me because I sync all my org files in a git repository and can access them from almost every computer with git and emacs installed, and also because org mode has this nice agenda view that reminds of what to do for the day.

Meanwhile I also like to keep the benefit of using mylyn in java project just because it manages the programming context. If we have a org mode connector for mylyn to sync mylyn tasks with org files, that will be perfect.

If there's no such a mylyn connector to org files, can someone suggest a free task repository that works well with Mylyn? Right now I'm using Mylyn with github issue list. It's good, but it's missing some fundamental features such as keeping track of time on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I talked people from Tasktop, (who are the mylyn developers) but unfortunately there is no such a connector at this time.